# validar con jquery.validate un formulario con elementos dinamicos dividido en tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony2, jquery-validate

el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

En twig a partir del form-wizard de la plantilla metronic creo de foma dinámica tanto los tabs como los elementos dentro de ellos.
Esta primera parte sale bien, el problema esta en la validación. Todos los campos son obligatorios y cuando le cuando le doy al boton de siguiente solo valida el primer campo y si los demas se quedan en blanco pasa de pagina como si todo estuviera bien.

Si le doy click a cada campo, si se muestra como required y si lo dejo en blanco me sale el cartel de campo requerido, pero cuando le doy al boton de siguiente, si el primer campo esta bien, quita el error y pasa al siguiente tab.

Alguien tiene alguna idea o solución???

Answer (score 1):

El problema eran los `name` de cada elemento. Los `id` los hacía únicos cuando definía los elementos:

```
id="anxAct{{ partida.id }}"
```

Pero el name no lo definía; y entre la documentación que lei de jquery.validate, estaba que **da problemas tanto cuando el `id` se repite como cuando el `name` se repite**.

Por tanto hice lo mismo con el `name` que con el `id`, y ya esta; solucionado el problema. Ahora sí valida todos los campos y no pasa al siguiente. Espero que la sirva a alguien y se evite perder tiempo con tan simple solución que tenía.